PoE WiFi client with ethernet output
I live in a small residential apartment, and I use the residence's WiFi provider to get my internet access.
I use a standard WiFi PCIe card with two small external antennas on my desktop PC.
Unfortunately, the PC is placed in a corner where the WiFi signal reception/transmission quality is poor (I've spotted places in my apartment where WiFi signal quality is way better) but I can't move my PC in the apartment due to space constraints.
I need a device that matches the following criterias :

Allow me to place it freely in the apartment, where signal quality is best.
Output a wired (gigabit) ethernet connection, as I want my internet traffic to pass through my managed switch before reaching my PC's ethernet port.
It should be powered by active PoE (IEEE-802.3-af or IEEE-802.3-at compliant, not using passive PoE adapters) so that I can power it directly through my switch.

The description of the product can ressemble the one of a Wireless Access Point in client or bridge mode, but really I don't need all the features of an access point and I don't need to redistribute the WiFi or have other devices connect to it. I only need to "externalize" my WiFi adapter and make it output ethernet.
The best way I could name this device would be a "PoE WiFi client" but it didn't lead to much results.
Also, the residence's WiFi doesn't just simply need an SSID and password to connect to it, it has a dedicated login webpage where you enter your account credentials. I don't know how the device would handle that.

Automatic handling of the captive portal might be pretty tough. Would it be acceptable to login to the captive portal on your PC instead of having the AP handle it automatically? Also, what's your budget? And what Wi-Fi standard is the apartment using (e.g. Wi-Fi 6, 6E, 7)?

@JMY1000 Yes, I would connect to the captive portal using my PC, for my budget I would say a maximum of $200 and the ISP's standard is Wi-Fi 5 (and it's on 5 GHz mode).

There are plenty of PoE access points out there, many of which can act as a bridge to forward the network from WiFi to a wired network. (Like this one, they are most commonly geared toward outdoor use.) The problem is the captive portal. For that you want a "Travel Router" that has software built to handle that. I am not aware of any travel routers that also have PoE. Those two areas don't really overlap.
There are ways to clone your MAC address from the computer you signed in with over to the access point, but then you usually have to repeat the process every few days. (Not worth it)
I suggest you give up on the PoE requirement and get a travel router: TP Link Example. You could also try extending the antennas on your existing WiFi adapter and placing them in a better location: RP-SMA cable
Notes about extending your antennas: Keep the extension as short as neccessary. There are 30ft cables, but you loose signal over the cable length, so don't buy one that is longer than necessary. Most WiFi antennas use "Reverse Polarity SMA" but not all. Make sure you check your WiFi adapter.
